# jQuery - animate moving elements without overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make my menu items move around in random positions without overlapping on top of each other. I'm using `animate` with `top` `left` properties and obviously for them to work I made the position property to `absolute`.

Now the problem with this approach is that they will overlap on top when I just want them to bounce off each other.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

```
function Menu($item) {
    this.item = $item;
};

Menu.prototype.makeNewPosition = function ($container) {
    var h = $container.height() - 50;
    var w = $container.width() - 50;

    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [nh, nw];
};


Menu.prototype.move = function () {
    var that = this;
    $.each(this.item, function(index, value) {
        var newq = that.makeNewPosition($(value).parent());

        $(value).animate({
        top: newq[0],
        left: newq[1]
    }, 2000, function() {
        that.move();
    });
    });
};

var $menu = new Menu($('.nav li'));
$menu.move();
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sungsoonz/wzmh63xb/19/)

Comment: you're asking for a phsyics engine.. basically at each frame you want to see if they overlap, then calculate where they should move after on the next frame. which doesn't come out of the box with jquery animate

Comment: Yeah, like @Daemedeor you're gonna need something like PhysicsJS or some sort of physics engine for this. http://wellcaffeinated.net/PhysicsJS/#demo-4

Comment: if you wanted to keep what you have without a crazy write (it'll be sluggish though) is to when "makeNewPosition" does a calculation, you check the other elements and see if there is an overlap in the new position (especially since you know how big each element is) and then if there is overlap, calculate the new position by using phsyics to calculate the bounce... i know in general what to do... but it wouldn't be a short write, this is what physics... but its worth it imo, since it is a big thing now.. just would take a while

Comment: some good sources f you don't want to write it, then look at the aforementioned physicsjs, gsock, famo.us, velocity.js or even this tutorial: http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-2d-physics-engine-the-basics-and-impulse-resolution--gamedev-6331